# SAP UI5 Upload image file using OData

Tags: file-upload, upload, sapui5

**UI5 code is:**

```
<u:FileUploader id="fileUploader" fileType="txt,jpg,png,js" placeholder="Choose a file for Upload..."></u:FileUploader>
<Button text="Upload File" press="fnUplodImage" />
```

**Below is my controller code to upload image**

```
var fileAddress = this.byId("fileUploader");
var file = jQuery.sap.domById(fileAddress.FUEl.id).files[0];
console.log(fileAddress);
var oModelUpload = this.getView().getModel("rulelist2");
oModelUpload.setUseBatch(false);
var oData = {
 Zidentifier1: 'abcd',
 Zidentifier2: '555555',
 Filename: "" + file.name + ""
};
oModelUpload.update("/Ven_FileSet(Zidentifier1='" + oData.Zidentifier1 + "',Zidentifier2='" + oData.Zidentifier2 + "',Filename='" +
 oData.Filename + "')", oData, {
  "method": "PUT",
  success: function(data) {
   console.log("success");
  },
  error: function(e) {
   console.log(e);
  }
 });
```

> **error - The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the resource identified by the Data Service Request URI.
>            Can anyone find where I am wrong within this flow ?**

Comment: the message probably comes from missing media settings on the odata service.

Comment: Can you give me exact solution

Comment: No, it's a pretty open ended question. Have a google for "sap odata create stream" and you'll find plenty of blogs and how-to's.

Comment: yes i googled it but not able to get solution

Answer (score 0):

You should create another service only for receiving uploaded file, and use it like this:

```
<u:FileUploader uploadUrl="uploadURL/"
```

Comment: But i have to send data through the given service only i.e /sap/opu/odata/sap/ZNEW_MEDIA_SRV/Ven_FileSet(Zidentifier1='M1',Zidentifier2='41',Filename='image.jpeg')/$value

Comment: the odata service cannot save an uploaded file.